# smoothness and convexity of optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-smooth-optimization

suppose we have an optimization problem in high dimension, how can detect it is smooth problem or convex problem or non of them to apply appropriate tools for solve it?

thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can't really detect it. You know it/learn it/prove it when you study the problem.